# Unable to close a accordion menu in react native after picking an item from it

Tags: android, react-native, accordion, react-native-paper

So I have a screen in react-native in my android app for reporting faulty equipment on my university and I have a wierd issue with my accordion menu. I use it as a list of options for the type of broken equipment that I store and then send to the database. After testing I found out the acordion menu doesnt close even if I edit the function to change the state that should track if the menu shoudl be open or not. Anybody any ideas?

```
const [typeOfEquip, setTypeOfEquip] = useState('');
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(true);



const chooseType= (typ) =>{
setTypeOfEquip(typ);
handlePress();
```

}

```
const handlePress = () => setExpanded(!expanded);


<List.AccordionGroup>
          <List.Accordion
            title="Type of equipment"
            expanded={expanded}
            onPress={handlePress}
            id="1">
            <List.Item
              title="Svetla"
              onPress={() => {
                chooseType('Svetla');
              }}
            />
            <List.Item
              title="Stoličky"
              onPress={() => {
                chooseType('Stoličky');
              }}
            />
          </List.Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are having this issue because of default behaviour. In `onPress` of
`List.Accordion` you are calling `handlePress()` and children of `List.Accordion` which is `List.Item` calling `chooseType` function. `chooseType` also calls `handlePress` function inside. Try adding `e.preventDefault()` to functions

```
const [typeOfEquip, setTypeOfEquip] = useState('');
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(true);



const chooseType= (e, typ) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  setTypeOfEquip(typ);
  handlePress(); 
}

const handlePress = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setExpanded(!expanded);
}


<List.AccordionGroup>
          <List.Accordion
            title="Type of equipment"
            expanded={expanded}
            onPress={handlePress}
            id="1">
            <List.Item
              title="Svetla"
              onPress={(e) => {
                chooseType(e, 'Svetla');
              }}
            />
            <List.Item
              title="Stoličky"
              onPress={(e) => {
                chooseType(e, 'Stoličky');
              }}
            />
          </List.Accordion>
```

Comment: And what does the e mean? Or more specificaly where does the app get it from? The accordion is also from react native paper. Its also good to mention this is an android app I think.